# Delay time in cooking brined meat

Tags: food-safety

I'm taking my day and a half brined chicken breast out of the brine today.  Unfortunately I can't cook them for 2 days since I won't be home.  Is it okay to cook brined meat at a later date?

Comment: Was it refrigerated while brining? Do you plan on storing it in the fridge until cooking?

Comment: Brining doesn't matter, the storage time is as for any meat.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be 100% fine, as long as you store it like you would store any other raw products, same rules pretty much apply, but you can probably get a few more days of life out of it because of the higher con

Answer (score -1):

you can cook it later if refrigerated, if not keep it in a cool spot like a veggie cellar and back in freash brin.